# How to attach different indices to an html element with jinja?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am creating a simple html questionnaire document, as a base template I am using the following jinja code:

```
from jinja2 import Template

title = ['1 title', '2 title']
message = ['1 message', '2 message']

template = Template(
"""
{% macro create_block(title, message) %}

<h1> {{title}} </h1>
<h3>question?</h3>


<input type="radio" value="val1" name="question1_{{ i }}">option A</input>
<input type="radio" value="val2" name="question1_{{ i }}">option B</input>


<h3>question 2?</h3>
<input type="radio" value="one" name="question1_{{ i }}">a</input>
<input type="radio" value="two" name="question1_{{ i }}">b</input>
<input type="radio" value="three" name="question1_{{ i }}">c</input>

{% endmacro %}

{% for title, message in list %}
{{ create_block(title, message) }}
{% endfor %}

""")

print_html(template.render(list=zip(title, message)))
```

The above template creates questions sets for the number of elements in title and message lists. For example, for two elements in `title`, the above code will generate two different questionnaire sets. However, to produce a valid html document I would like to vary the `{{i}}` parameter in `name="question1_{{ i }}`. For the above template, the expected output looks like this:

```
<h1>
 1 title
</h1>
<h3>
 question?
</h3>
<input name="question1_1" type="radio" value="val1"/>
option A
<input name="question1_1" type="radio" value="val2"/>
option B
<h3>
 question 2?
</h3>
<input name="question1_2" type="radio" value="one"/>
a
<input name="question1_2" type="radio" value="two"/>
b
<input name="question1_2" type="radio" value="three"/>
c
<h1>
 2 title
</h1>
<h3>
 question?
</h3>
<input name="question2_1" type="radio" value="val1"/>
option A
<input name="question2_1" type="radio" value="val2"/>
option B
<h3>
 question 2?
</h3>
<input name="question2_2" type="radio" value="one"/>
a
<input name="question2_2" type="radio" value="two"/>
b
<input name="question2_2" type="radio" value="three"/>
c
```

In Jinja, what is the correct way to get the above output with the indices of the checkboxes names varying?

Comment: I tried to `{% for i in title %} {% endfor %}`. However, for some reason it takes "title" as a string, instead of a list object. Any idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would pass the index as an argument just like you did for the others.

```
from jinja2 import Template

title = ['1 title', '2 title']
message = ['1 message', '2 message']
indices = list(range(len(title)))

template = Template(
"""
{% macro create_block(title, message, i) %}

<h1> {{title}} </h1>
<h3>question?</h3>


<input type="radio" value="val1" name="question1_{{ i }}">option A</input>
<input type="radio" value="val2" name="question1_{{ i }}">option B</input>


<h3>question 2?</h3>
<input type="radio" value="one" name="question1_{{ i }}">a</input>
<input type="radio" value="two" name="question1_{{ i }}">b</input>
<input type="radio" value="three" name="question1_{{ i }}">c</input>

{% endmacro %}

{% for title, message, i in list %}
{{ create_block(title, message, i) }}
{% endfor %}

""")

print_html(template.render(list=zip(title, message, indices)))
```

Comment: I tried this code and I am getting a blank output, any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: Note that this line `...` in my answer was referring to what you wrote in your code.

Comment: I know the meaning of `...` however it is still showing nothing when I put the other remaining part of the code, could you put the full solution so I can accept the answer? Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake on this line `print_html(template.render(list=zip(title, message, indices)))`.

Comment: Was supposed to change `list` to `document` but your edit should work now.

Comment: Even with that the indices are wrong, any idea of how to get the same expected output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228154/discussion-between-nerveless-child-and-anon).